# Terraform list of objects default values

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I'm getting an error when I try to set default values for an object inside a list:

```
variable "routes" {
  type = list(object({
    destination_cidr_block = string
    blackhole = bool})
    default = {
      blackhole = "false"
      destination_cidr_block = ""
    })
  description = "a list of objects containing the cidr blocks of the dest and whether the cidr is a blackhole or not."
  default = null
}
```

When I run this, I get the below error:

```
Error: Missing argument separator

  on variables.tf line 21, in variable "routes":
  18:   type = list(object({
  19:     destination_cidr_block = string
  20:     blackhole = bool})
  21:     default = {

A comma is required to separate each function argument from the next.
```

Line 21 "default" is underlined in the error.

Setting defaults in this way works fine when it's just an object by itself.  I don't know why it complains when the variable is a list of objects.

Comment: You have a typo where the closing `)` for the `object` is on your fourth line. Place it on the correct seventh line and you will be good to go.

Comment: @MattSchuchard I don't think that's the issue.  That same syntax works fine if it's just a single object and not a list of object.

Answer (score 4):

You may want to have it like this:

```
variable "routes" {
  type = list(object({
    destination_cidr_block = string
    blackhole              = bool
  }))
  default = [{
    blackhole              = "false"
    destination_cidr_block = ""
  }]
  description = "a list of objects containing the cidr blocks of the dest and whether the cidr is a blackhole or not."
}
```

You cannot really have a `default` inside a type.

Comment: That fixes the error, but it's still not quite what I want.  I'm trying to make "blackhole" optional by providing a default value for it.

Comment: This may be possible with using `optional` and `default`. These are experimental features. Source: https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/defaults.html

Comment: Using optional did the trick.  I'll show an example of what I did.

Comment: It's kind of dumb though that it forces you to specify the types inside the object, but it won't let you set defaults for those types.

Comment: The type system of Terraform it is a bit limited at this moment, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

I [requested an object type default feature](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/30750) and they are now releasing [Optional attributes for object type constraints](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/releases/tag/v1.3.0-rc1) into the next build of Terraform!